# Same Display to all Screen Resolution (PC/Mobile/Tablet)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build my own photo gallery site, and I just need some quick solution to my problem.

Overview: A photo gallery website with problems on displaying in different screen resolution.

Problem: If the screen resolution of the viewer is greater than of 13" screen, the navigation or menu is at the left side. And when viewed in a smaller screen size such as tablets and phones, the navigation is at the top and only shows a scrolling page with a single image at view at its screen display at a time. You can see the difference when you zoom in and out of the my site indicated above.

What must be done to fix the display to the one with navigation on the left even when viewed with phones and tablets?

Comment: I already removed the links of my website since the question has already been answered within 10 minutes after posting by the person below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a non-responsive site????  Okay, I'll avoid making comments about why you should leave the responsive behavior, but maybe you have the only site on the planet that no one ever visits on a mobile device.  Here's how you do it...

In your main.css file there is a media query for the header elements that starts somewhere around line 119:

```
@media (min-width:1000px) {
```

Remove this line and it's closing `}` somewhere around line 245.

Then delete the entire media query and it's contents beginning at line 539 and ending around 602:

/

```
*  Responsive code  */

    @media (max-width:1100px){

        header{ 

        ...

        #map{
            margin: 0!important;
        }
    }
```

If you also want the portfolio images to not scale remove the last media query and it's contents:

```
@media (max-width:550px){
     .main .work{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: and must removed the : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />` from html file.

Comment: Thank you so much! This thread is closed.